# Why go build/install updates required packages automatically?

Tags: go, go-modules

I have an issue with the current version of the grpc-go package. So I want to use the previous version of the package. I used the following command to change the required version:

```
go get google.golang.org/grpc@v1.26.0
```

But now when I want to use `go build` or `go install`, go always updates the required version to the current `v1.27.0` so I am running always to the issue.

How can I prevent that go is not updating the required packages to the latest version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I used an other module what required the version `v1.27.0`. This was one of my own modules so I just changed the requirement in this module to a lower version of `grpc-go`.